# Should I save GeoIP data

Tags: database, geolocation, geoip, maxmind

I'm currently working on a project in which I  will use geolocation data, base on GeoIP. This data will be quite important for us, so I want to ask you whether it makes sense to save the exact geolocation data for IP each to database immediately, or just write only ip, and then pull the geolocation data at the time when they are needed. We relay on http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/ and as you can see the database is updated each month, and as far as I understand there is a probability that a pool of IP can change the location? If anyone has had experience with a similar problem, I would ask for comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, IP address reallocated from time to time.

You need to save the location at the time of query.

An IP address located in UK might be used in France next year.